# Mongoose find is not working with query object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning `node.js` with `mongo db`. I have a code to fetch records and that works fine

```
await studentModel.find({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
      students= data.map((d) => {
        return new InterviewQuestion(d['roll_no'], d['name']);
      });
    });
```

but when I want to filter them then the query doesn't return any record

```
await studentModel.find({sClass: sClass}, (err, data) => { //sClassis a field in document and also the name of variable
    if (err) throw err;
      students= data.map((d) => {
        return new InterviewQuestion(d['roll_no'], d['name']);
      });
    });
```

Comment: if you want to find main problem, you can add controller, route, schema to the question, and request

Answer (score 1):

when you use async/await don't use callback and use try/catch in async/await approach
so you can do like this

```
try {
  let data = await studentModel.find({});
  students = data.map((d) => {
    return new InterviewQuestion(d["roll_no"], d["name"]);
  });
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}

try {
  let data = await studentModel.find({ sClass: sClass });
  students = data.map((d) => {
    return new InterviewQuestion(d["roll_no"], d["name"]);
  });
} catch (err) {
  throw err;
}
```

this query is correctly

```
await studentModel.find({ sClass: sClass })
```

also you can try this :

```
await studentModel.find({ sClass})
```

your issue from another thing, because I tested the queries every things is OK

Comment: Why can't I used call back with async methods? I heard callback are best for handling asyn requests. Also my code without filter works.

Comment: where did you heard callback are best for handling async requests??

Comment: Everywhere, as an example https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp

Comment: you can use async/await with try/catch togheter or a promise function without await with .then().catch() or a function with callback, there are 3 approach

Answer (score 0):

I used a different name for the variable `sClass` and then it worked. I am still wondering why it is not allowed to have a filter variable with the same name as of document field.